# How does Oracle NoSQL DB Streams handles failures?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I had set up several NoSQL streams this morning. Around mid-day, there were issues with the network connectivicity in the environment where Oracle NoSQL Database was deployed. I saw some anomalies in my applications.

How does Oracle NoSQL DB Streams API handle failures like unstable network connection, master transfer, and rebalance at the server?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying Oracle NoSQL Database Streams API.

Oracle NoSQL Streams handles failures in different ways depending on the nature of the failure. In the case of unstable network connectivity, the Streams API would reconnect to the master node of each shard at the host and port cached in the Streams API, therefore, when network connectivity restores, the Streams API would reconnect successfully and resume streaming from the last streamed operation. If the attempts to reconnect fail after three times, the Streams API would refresh the topology from the Oracle NoSQL Database, and reconnect with the master node found in the latest store topology. This happens when the master transfers and the old master is no longer accessible.

Handling store rebalancing is similar to handling master transfer, the Streams API would pull the new topology from the store, and locate the new master of each shard to reconnect. After the rebalancing is complete and the new topology is ready, the Streams API would be able to reconnect and resume streaming.

The description above is for the latest version Oracle NoSQL Database 21.1. In previous versions, there is a limit that caps the number of reconnects in Stream API, and the Streams API will terminate the stream and signal `NoSQLSubscriber.onError()` if it runs out of the maximum attempts. In 21.1, such limit is removed by default and the Streams API would just keep reconnecting till the connection is restored. The users can override the default behavior by setting `NoSQLSubscriptionConfig.Builder.setMaxReconnect(long maxReconnect)`